# SQL - error when copying an entire table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a duplicate copy of a table, that is copying the schema as well as data into a new table, but I have encountered some issues that I cannot really understand the error message.

My original table schema looks like below. There are 54 fields. For data protection issue, I have to block all the fieldnames.

[image]

I have created a new table, with the schema looks exactly the same except only one thing - it has a column with an auto-generated id (fieldname highlighted in red) for each record:

[image]

Then I ran the following command to copy data from table1 to table2:

```
insert into HDM_XXX.XXX.XXX_Table_2
select * from HDM_XXX.XXX.XXX_Table_1
```

But the follow error was generated:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2020-11-29T21:42:13.6804543+00:00
```

I would really appreciate any tips!

Comment: it's not "exactly the same except for one thing", the column types start being different around the 15th, and some of the varchars seem to have gotten narrower.

Comment: Best practice is to always explicitly list the columns for inserts and selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all the columns in common!

```
insert into HDM_XXX.XXX.XXX_Table_2 ( col1, col2, . . . )
    select col1, col2, . . .
    from HDM_XXX.XXX.XXX_Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to create the table and insert the data at the same time:

```
SELECT  IDENTITY(1,1) AS Compliance_Id
,       *
INTO    your_table_copy
FROM    your_table
```